# is INSERT ON CONFLICT UPDATE from WITH query possible in postgresql 9.5?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, with-statement, postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to insert (or update on conflict) rows from CTE but struggling to find right syntax for it. The table I'm inserting in looks like this (Simplified for the sake of clarity)

```
        Column        |           Type           |                            Modifiers
----------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------
 id                   | integer                  | not null default nextval('"QuestionStatistic_id_seq"'::regclass)
 questionId           | integer                  |
 count                | integer                  | not null default 0
Indexes:
    "QuestionStatistic_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "QuestionStatistic_questionId_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree ("questionId")
```

This is my query:

```
with "Statistic" as (
   select "questionId", "count" from "SomeTable"
)
INSERT INTO "QuestionStatistic" ("questionId", "count") SELECT "questionId", "count" FROM "Statistics" 
ON CONFLICT ("questionId") DO UPDATE SET "count" = "Statistics"."count"
```

which gives me `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "Statistics"` on `SET "count" = "Statistics"."count"` part. 
I also tried to add FROM to update clause but got `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"`. Is there a way to make INSERT ON CONFLICT UPDATE work with CTE?

Comment: maybe you should use `excluded.count`?.. would you please share repeatable sandbox?..

Comment: @VaoTsun thanks, using "excluded" as table name works just fine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html

> The `SET` and `WHERE` clauses in `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` have access to the existing row using the table's name (or an alias), and to rows proposed for insertion using the special **`excluded`** table.

thus try:

```
with "Statistic" as (
   select "questionId", "count" from "SomeTable"
)
INSERT INTO "QuestionStatistic" ("questionId", "count")
SELECT "questionId", "count" FROM "Statistics" 
ON CONFLICT ("questionId") DO UPDATE 
SET "count" = excluded."count"
```